# Word for feeling in the mood to experiment

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, synonyms

I am looking for a word for being in a mood to experiment or try something you would not normally do for a situation.

A person might say: "*I am feeling .... today, and will go another way*".

I knew this word but for some reason I am totally blanking on it at the moment.
I think the word starts with the letter *t*.

Comment: What's wrong with *experimental*?

Comment: I've heard people say "in an experimental mood."

Comment: Bi-curious.... I'll get my coat.

Comment: @AlecTeal semi-obligatory: http://xkcd.com/330/

Answer (score 24):

I would use *adventurous*.  It is commonly used in this situation.

Comment: Thanks, but not the word I was looking for. I think the word starts with the letter t.

Answer (score 6):

### Word starting with T

<sub>Since you mention **t** in your comment to Chenmunka...</sub>

> **[tem·er·ar·i·ous](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/temerarious)**  [tem-uh-rair-ee-uhs] *adjective*
>
> reckless; rash.

### Alternatives

> [**saucy**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/saucy) *adjective* ˈsȯ-sē, ˈsa-
>
> **2 a** :  impertinently bold and impudent
>
> **b** :  amusingly forward and flippant

Usage: "[Not today my good man, I'm feeling saucy.](http://youtu.be/FOt3r_aNNxE?t=49s)"

Saucy in your example would be a *saucy* word choice.

Comment: I like the word, but `temerarious` to me implies recklessness (as in the definition), while CaptainABC's example in the question doesn't. (That might just be my reading of the example though?)

Comment: @voretaq Could be, but temerarious is the only synonym for `adventerous`/`experimental` that I could find. As it is based on `temerity`, which can mean simply **bold**, I think it still fits.

Comment: @PatrickM Yeah I could get behind it, it just seems like it has baggage (for that matter so does my idea of `temperamental`). I can't think of many T words that fit here :)

Answer (score 3):

"I'm feeling "enterprising" today?"

> [enterprising](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/enterprising): ready to embark on new ventures; full of boldness a d initiative.

Also, consider "intrepid" and "in a trying mood."

> [intrepid](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Intrepid): fearless; daring; bold.
>
> I am feeling **in a trying mood** today, and will go another way."

On fairly different levels, how about "frivolous," "frilly," "frothy," and "[transgressive](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/transgressive)"?

> I am feeling **frivolous** today, and will go another way."
>
> I am feeling **[transgressive](http://www.rockwoodleadership.org/article.php?id=256)** today, and will go another way."

Comment: OED says of ***temerarious*** "now only *literary*", and they record no citations after C19.

Answer (score 2):

*Experimental*!

"Feeling *experimental*, I put the odd looking delicacy to my nose and sniffed".

Or

"I am feeling *experimental* today, and will go another way"!

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work as a single word but you could use "tempted" in combination with another verb.

> "I am feeling tempted to experiment today, and will go another way"

Answer (score 1):

In response to your comment about a word starting with t, how about this?

*I feel like trailblazing today*

That implies going where you have not been before.

Answer (score 0):

I'm feeling frisky today, and hear the wayward call of the wild in my restless soul. The path not taken beckons me with a [Siren's song](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siren_%28mythology%29).

Comment: I would caution that in pop culture, *frisky* has connotations of playful sexual interest or arousal.

Comment: I like frisky here.  OP didn't say this wasn't about sex.

Comment: @choster Sure, but it would be a duller language if our word choices were always confined to hooking up with current pop culture intimations, you know?

Comment: My, downvoters dredging the depths of time! They must be feeling *frisky* today.

Answer (score 0):

Today, I've decided that I'm going to:

Cut loose / live dangerously / let it all hang out / let the mood take me where it will / be a {daredevil / free spirit} / {venture / step} outside (of) my comfort zone / try something {new / different} / {throw / cast} caution to the wind.

Answer (score -1):

[Eccentric](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=eccentric&oq=eccentric&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.4416j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8) - unconventional and slightly strange

[Deviant](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/deviant) - differing from a norm or from the accepted standards of a society

[Wayward](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/wayward) - given to or marked by willful, often perverse deviation from what is desired, expected, or required in order to gratify one's own impulses or inclinations **or** swayed or prompted by caprice; unpredictable

[Capricious](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=capricious&oq=capricious&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.3935j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8) - given to sudden and unaccountable changes of mood or behaviour

... or any number of synonyms of the above which can be discovered by clicking on the links.

Answer (score -1):

Since you're looking for a T-word, maybe *Temperamental*?

> [temperamental](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/temperamental): given to erratic behavior; unpredictable.

I'm not sure I like it in your example, but it's the first T-word that came to mind.
([Capricious](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/capricious) also came to mind but it's not a T-word and I'm not sure I really like that one in the example either...)

Answer (score -1):

I cannot start it with a "T" but the word I would choose would be **venturesome**.

Answer (score -1):

Some more words with 'T':

[Tractile/tracility](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/tractile): Means [ductile](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/ductile), which can be defined as *capable of being readily persuaded or influenced; [tractable](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tractable)*.

[Transilient](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/transilient): *Leaping or passing from one thing or state to another.*